# Can I update Ubuntu from a point release CD?

Tags: updates, cd

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed and I am using a mobile broadband connection, so bandwidth is precious. What I would like to do is to enable only security updates.

Then when version 12.04.1 is released (which it already is), download it over a different connection (probably not on an Ubuntu machine) and burn it to disk, and then use it to update the system.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The alternate CD is actually a mini-apt repository. You can download the point release alternate CD and then insert it into the machine while it is booted up, after burning it.

Then go to Software Center-> Software Sources and use the `Add Volume` button to add the CD.

[image: The Software Sources <code>Add Volume</code> button]
<sub>Image credit Jorge Castro</sub>

This will work, but the CD does not contain every package which might be installed on your system, as it only contains what is needed to get a working system(except for some drivers). You still need to update any other packages you want to update using your internet connection(s).

The default packages (and a few more) will be updated to the point release version. These non-default packages were on the CD as they are commonly installed, but not installed by default. These may include common drivers.

## For Quantal and later:

Quantal no longer has an alternate CD. You can, however, use `AptOnCD` as follows:

Download `aptoncd` on a Ubuntu machine (of the same version and architecture(32/64-bit)) with a fast internet connection and install it:

```
sudo apt-get install aptoncd
```

And use the update manager to update packages. You can also select packages with:

```
sudo apt-get install --download-only [packages]
```

which should get packages and dependencies into the `apt` cache. You can then create an `aptoncd` CD and burn it with the packages it gives you from the selection. You can select any package that has been downloaded since the last `sudo apt-get autoclean` operation.

Comment: That's great ObsessiveFOSS, thank you. Is there any reason why this won't work with the regular desktop iso? I've read that the alternate CD image is being retired for future releases - how would I proceed in this case?

Comment: @TenLeftFingers The live CD does not contain .deb packages, but a full system, and only a few deb packages for small changes. You can't just copy the entire system over; it won't work. There is a method for Quantal and later; I'll post it when I have time.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers There are  Quantal instructions now.

Comment: Thank you ObsessiveSSOℲ. The AptOnCD requires an Ubuntu installation at the point of download - whereas my desktop will be staying put. Perhaps I can make a USB install and bring that with me. When the alternate CD is "merged" with the desktop CD as with Quantal, will the packages be present then?

Comment: @TenLeftFingers Unfortunately, it won't be merged. There sill be no CD with packages at all, and no point releases. You can try to install Ubuntu Quantal to a large USB stick or external hard disk(*full installation*) and try make the CD on that. With that said, Quantal is non-LTS and does not have point releases IIRC.